# Mongolia Visa-free regime

Tags: visas, mongolia, visa-free-entry, italian-citizens

I have recently contacted an agency for a trip I will make to Mongolia and on their website, in a quite hidden section, it says that Mongolia is now in a Visa-free regime for an extended list of countries until December (probably to promote tourism).

I don't think this is somehow misinformation: it would mean the agency won't be able to charge for visa so it's basically loss of money for them; moreover they refunded the money I paid for the visa application before I realised it was free.

However I am having some problems finding the same information elsewhere and my spider sense is tingling if you know what I mean.

Does anyone know a good authoritative source of information regarding this?

For further information, I am an Italian living in the UK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a visa if you stay up to 30 days in Mongolia. From [Mongolian Ministry of foreign affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.mn/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3446%3A42-&catid=43%3A2009-12-20-21-55-03&Itemid=62&lang=en):

> Within the framework of the 100 days of the intensification of economy
>   the Government of Mongolia approved a list of 42 countries with a visa
>   free access to Mongolia. According to this decision nationals of these
>   countries are entitled with the visa-free stay for up to 30 days for
>   tourist and short business trips from June 25, 2014 till 31st December
>   2015.
>
> The list includes the following countries: Republic of Austria,
>   Principality of Andorra...... **Italian Republic**, Republic of
>   Ireland....  Republic of
>   Estonia.

Answer (score 2):

Mongolia has a visa-free policy for selected countries until 31 December 2015.

http://www.mfa.gov.mn/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3446%3A42-&catid=43%3A2009-12-20-21-55-03&Itemid=62&lang=en